# dynamically added button on click not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a function in my own image browser that creates and displays a delete button when the user hovers the cursor over a certain image's div and hides the button when the user hover the mouse out of the div.

this is the code:

```
     function displayImages() {
        //run through array of images
        for (a = 0; a < images.length; a++) {

var container = document.createElement('div');
                container.id = 'container'+images[a];
                container.style.width = 120;
                container.style.backgroundColor = '#e9e9e9';
                container.style.height = 140;
                container.style.margin = 5;
                container.style.display = 'inline-block';
                container.style.float = 'left';
                var imageID = images[a];
                container.onmouseover = function() {imageRollover(this)};
                container.onmouseout = function() {imageMouseOut(this)};
    }       
   }


function imageRollover(image) {
        var trashcan = document.createElement('BUTTON');
        trashcan.id = 'trash'+image.id;
        trashcan.className = 'deleteButton';
        trashcan.onclick = function() {deleteImage(image.id);};
        document.getElementById(image.id).appendChild(trashcan);
    }



function imageMouseOut(image) {
    document.getElementById(image.id).removeChild(document.getElementById('trash'+image.id));
        }

function deleteImage(image) {
        alert(image);
    }
```

My problem is, that when I click `trashcan`, it calls nothing. I already tried to add the onlick event normally:
`trashcan.onclick = deleteImage(image.id);`
But then, for some reason, is calls the function when I hover my mouse over the `container`.

How do I make sure that on click events for dynamically added rollover buttons work?

The function can de viewed on: http://www.imaginedigital.nl/CMS/Editor/ImagePicker.html or http://jsfiddle.net/f239ymos/

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Error messages in the console? Perhaps you want trashcan.onclick = function() {deleteImage('"'+image.id+'"');}; Also if image is an `img` tag, the you cannot have a child

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: the image is displayed in 3 divs: 1 container, one image preview, which is an img tag, and another div that displays the image name. de container is the div that actually creates the child so that cannot cause the problem.

Comment: I added a link to the actual file, that might be even better?

Comment: i dont have access to script/html so I cant play around with it :P

Comment: `window.onload = loadImages();` needs to be `window.onload = loadImages;`

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing me to guess here(not giving a fiddle), and create a scenario of my own but from what I understand, you want a button to appear no hover, and when pressed to delete the image so here its a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mv1afds/)

hover functionality

```
$((document.body).on('mouseenter', '.test', function(){
    console.log('here');
    $(this).children('.test .x_butt').show();
});
$(document.body).on('mouseleave', '.test', function(){
    $('.test .x_butt').hide();
});
```

remove functionality

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.x_butt', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**P.S.** as for your dynamically added divs issue, the `$(selector1).on('click','selector2', function() {...});` deals with it, as long as `selector1` is not added dynamically. (`selector2` would be the div you want the function to be on) [demo with dynamically added elements](http://jsfiddle.net/hsrk2dtm/) ( click clone )

Comment: I don't think he's using jQuery.

Comment: if there is no reason he cant use it, why not use it :P

Comment: I thought a link to the website itself would be better. This is because the image picker loads all images from an API in the folder where these images are via xmlhttprequests. this typically does not get loaded by jsfiddle. despite of this, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/f239ymos/

Comment: no need for images :D, you didnt comment the answer though, you commented my comment above, can you use jquery??

Comment: I can but I prefer to keep working in plain javascript as my entire project works on it and i am unexperienced in jquery

Comment: the more you know the better, also much easier in jquery

Answer (score 0):

First change

`window.onload = loadImages();` to `window.onload = loadImages;`

Then since you pass an object you can change

```
function imageMouseOut(image) {
    document.getElementById(image.id).removeChild(document.getElementById('trash'+image.id));
}
```

to

```
function imageMouseOut(image) {
    image.removeChild(image.childNodes[0]);
}
```

However why not just hide and show the trashcan? Much cleaner